# $_GET always return 1

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, html-table

I've got a problem with passing GET variable to another PHP page. I've got a simple table of content. I would like to delete rows by using ajax. Ajax works perfectly on simple example with form.

Here is a markup:

```
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
/*here are rows(content) */

        <form action='#' method='get' onsubmit='deleteContent(); return false'>
        <td><input type='hidden' name='delete' value='$row[id_content]' id='delete' />
        <input type='submit' class='del'  name='delete' title='Delete' value='Delete' /></td>
        </tr></form>";  
    }
```

When I press the submit it always return 1. 
Here is the DeleteContent

```
  function deleteContent()//za brisanje dela
{
    try
    {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    if (xhr == null)
    {
        alert("Vaš brskalnik ne podpira AJAX-a!");
        return;
    }
    var url = "delete.php?delete=" + document.getElementById('delete').value;

    xhr.onreadystatechange = handler2; 
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send(null);
}

function handler2()
{
    if (xhr.readyState == 4)
    {
        if (xhr.status == 200)

            document.getElementById("delete").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        else
            alert("error!");
    }
}
```

And here is the delete.php

```
            <?php
            echo "<span>Content delete</span><br/>";
            if($_GET['delete'])
            {echo $_GET['delete'];}

    ?>
```

Does anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: please paste the complete code of deleteContent func and php code as well

Comment: Show the code of `deleteContent()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "it return 1"? please clarify what "it" refers to.

Comment: Just a try - is it possible you have name 'delete' for each row? Maybe the mistake you make is send all these inputs with the same name and then you only read first one. Try name='delete$row[id_content]', or work with delete[] as an array. If that is not the problem, please give us more code.

Comment: @ctrahey - It has to be a value of a single row. I' think is getting always the value of the firts row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an ID has to be unique in a document.

`document.getElementById('delete')` will always point at the same element.
Provide the used form as argument to deleteContent() and you will be able to retrieve the correct value:

```
<form action='#' method='get' onsubmit='return deleteContent(this);'>
```

....

```
function deleteContent(form)//za brisanje dela
{
    try
    {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    if (xhr == null)
    {
        alert("Vaš brskalnik ne podpira AJAX-a!");
        return;
    }
    var url = "delete.php?delete=" + form.delete.value;

    xhr.onreadystatechange = handler2; 
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send(null);
    return false;
}
```

What else: Your markup appears to be invalid, use e.g.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
/*here are rows(content) */

        echo "<tr><td>
              <form action='#' method='get' onsubmit='return deleteContent(this);'>
               <input type='hidden' name='delete' value='{$row[id_content]}' id='delete' />
               <input type='submit' class='del'  name='delete' title='Delete' value='Delete' />
              </form>
             </td></tr>";  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Write *value* of `Value` attribute.

```
<input type='hidden' 
       name='delete' 
       value="<?php echo $row['id_content'] ?>" 
       id='delete' />
```